# Transparent background overlapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple view like this:

```
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.8)',position:'absolute',left:0,width:100,height:100}}></View>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.8)',position:'absolute',left:50,width:100,height:100}}></View>
```

but the overlap produces a color of it's own like this:

[image]

how do I make them both be only transparent towards the background and not overlap the transparency ?

Comment: Both are `width: 100`, and they're only set 50 units (pixels probably) apart (`left: 0` to `left: 50`), there's bound to be overlapping colors if you do this

Comment: @Samathingamajig the overlapping is intentional to describe my problem

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have transparency, or you don't overlap the views. Overlapping transparent views will always show whatever was behind the front views.

There is no magic way to tell a view in front to use its transparency and ignore any transparency behind. This is because the views are drawn back to front. So by the time the front view renders its transparency, then everything behind it is already drawn and finalized.

This is like overlapping a yellow plastic film and a green plastic film, and asking how can light can only go through the green one. That's just... not how it works.

Comment: removing overlap would be impossible but is there some other way I can use to at least make it seem like it's not overlapping transparency wise?

Comment: As Alex said, the other option is `rgb(82, 82, 82)`

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are really trying to solve here, but but if you can't stop them from overlapping then you must not use a non-partially transparent background color. If you can do neither of those, then the solution you are pursuing is impossible. Maybe it's time to rethink your strategy on this.